# Comparing elements by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

Ok I am trying to check if the value of the attribute `value` is equal to some string. If I call alert it to tell me if that is true, it will be true but I can't add class if that statement is true. What I am doing wrong ?

```
<div class="firstch" value="20:30">TEST</div>
```

```css
div {
    display:block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.disable {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
var attr = $('.firstch').attr('value');

if ( attr === '20:30') {
    $(this).addClass('disable');
} else {
    alert('YEah right -_-');
}
```

The code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kvjtpgv/11/)

Comment: in your current code $(this)  is referrring to window  replace it with class name

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `value` attribute to a div. As per this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) only 
`<button>, <option>, <input>, <li>, <meter>, <progress>, <param>` has this *value* attribute. So you can add a custom [**data**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute to this div

Secondly you are trying to refer using *this* inside the `if` loop. But here `$(this)` will fail, since you are not looping over any jquery object. Instead it is just comparing and equality check. So you need to refer to the element using a proper selector.

Hope this snippet will be useful

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstch" data-value="20:30">TEST</div> // Note use of data attribute
```

**JS**

```
 var attr = $('.firstch').attr('data-value');

 // For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others, `attr` is false. Check for both.
 if (attr === '20:30') {
   $('.firstch').addClass('disable');
 } else {
   alert('YEah right -_-');
 }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4kvjtpgv/12/)

Comment: Nicely done.  :)  Also, consider storing the selected element and the "magic string" of 20:30 to meaningfully-named variables.  `var disableValue = "20:30";  var firstch = $('.firstch');  if (firstch.attr('data-value') === disableValue) {  firstch.addClass('disable'); } else { alert ('Yeah right -_-'); }`

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. The problem is that `this` refers to the `document` object in your code. Change it to:

```
$('.firstch').addClass('disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong to add class

```
$(this).addClass('disable');
```

here $(this) is the **window** object, you should use the correct selector for the element where you want to add the class.